# macbook pro 2019: text garbled on Google Chrome preferences and others

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome

I got this annoying garbled text after I had updated to MacOS Big Sur (Version 11.0.1).
I came across this problem immediately I got updated and opened my chrome.
it looks like this:[image]

I also found something interesting. all the Latin letters changed into its next letter in order. and the space " "is changed into "!". For example, the text over my avatar is "**Zpv**!**boe**!Hpphmf", but the orginal is "**you** **and** google". like "**you**" goes "**zpv**", "**and**" becomes "**boe**" . I think that's wired!
I also got another thing that I wanted to mention. when I highlight the garbled text, it will get normal.
[image]

I tried to solve this tricky problem. First, I rebooted my Mac, but it didn't work. Then I changed UTF-8 which is a default encoding to ASCII, however, it was not helpful. Finally I called the Applecare, apple's technique support. She is very kind and she tell that I should wait for next Chrome's update. I think it will be OK although the garbled text makes me inconvenient.
Now I got crazy because I browsed a webpage and it's also garbled! I'm sure I can't ignore it any more.

[image]

My question is what can cause this and how can I solve it. Thank you advanced.

Answer (score 1):

This is a font issue, causing characters to be shifted by one (somehow!).

Uninstall *Roboto* from your system.

Source:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/ki7qss/strange_text_showing_in_chrome_started_after/
- https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/86605680?hl=en